# pandas set_index in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have lots of DataFrames of approximately this type:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x1 = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((np.random.random((3, 25)),np.arange(1,26))).T, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'timestamp'])
x2 = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((np.random.random((3, 25)),np.arange(1,26))).T, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'timestamp'])
x3 = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((np.random.random((3, 25)),np.arange(1,26))).T, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'timestamp'])
```

and in case I can not set the index on creation of the DataFrame, I thought to use a for-loop to change the timestamp column to the index of all of the DataFrames at once, like:

```
for x in [x1, x2, x3]:
    x = x.set_index(['timestamp'])
```

but when I then call `x1.head()` I get back

```
          a         b         c  timestamp
0  0.896372  0.320966  0.601483        1.0
1  0.041191  0.398337  0.778510        2.0
2  0.807218  0.891364  0.044076        3.0
3  0.604762  0.814592  0.731940        4.0
4  0.453155  0.122674  0.287158        5.0
```

Am I mis-using set_index() or misunderstanding how x1, x2 and x3 are assigned to x in the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set index *inplace*, when you loop through the list, *x* is just a temporary variable, which shares the same data as `x1`, `x2` and `x3`, assigning a new data frame to a temporary variable won't change the original data frame, you have to modify the data inplace:

```
for x in [x1, x2, x3]:
    x.set_index(['timestamp'], inplace=True)
```

[image]

---

Anther way to obtain a list of data frames you need without modifying the original data frames is to use list-comprehension:

```
[x.set_index(['timestamp']) for x in [x1, x2, x3]]
```

Comment: I see that you edited your answer, and that the use of `inplace = True` works. The question then, is why does the assignment _not_ work?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! That makes more sense now.

Comment: My reasoning about this is that a simple assignment is interpreted as creating a new variable which has nothing to do with what the variable points to originally, modifying data inplace should be the way to go. But unless you have to, this is actually not recommended.

Comment: I know! I try to avoid modifying data inplace if I can, so I used the assignment, but I guess this is the only way to go here. Anyways, thanks for the help!

Comment: @notlink put another way... when you do `x = x.set_index(...)`, at that point `x` is a reference to an object.  Then you overwrite that variable name and point the name `x` at a different object (a copy of the old dataframe with a shiny new index).  By using `inplace=True` you don't point `x` at a different object, but rather tell it to set the index of the object it currently points at.  This either helps clarify or further confuses.

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks for the comment. I think that helps. But why doesn't the assignment `x = x.set_index(..)` work while in that loop? `x` should be pointing at a specific object at that time, no? And, why would it work in a list comprehension and not in a for-loop? I just want to understand if I am missing something fundamental about object assignment.